# C++ runtime decision for a template type

Tags: c++, templates, types, runtime

```
 template<typename T>
 class A
 { std::vector<T> v;
   .... //other variables
   void op1();
   void op2();
   ... //other operations
 };

 int main()
 {
   string type;
   cout<<"which type do you need?"
   cin>>type;
   if(type=="int")
      A<int> ai;
   else  A<float> af;

   return 0;
 }
```

In both blocks I must do the same flow of instructions.
for example:

```
 ai.op1();
 ai.op2();
 ...
```

If they are only two I can write it two times but it is a horrible solution with a lot of conditions. Is there a way to do this once for a chosen type after "if-else"? I can't say which type wil be chosen? How should I do?

Comment: You'd have to do them all: templates are a compile-time-only concept.

Comment: I could do a function op_all() {op1(); op2();}? Is it good enough?

Comment: Look at Juan's solution, it's pretty much as good as it gets. The key is that in your code you will have to list a template expansion for every type that can be given to the template at runtime.

Comment: It's not too far from runtime preprocessor macros redefinition...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a function template:

```
template <typename T>
void do_stuff()
{
  A<T> ai;
  ai.op1();
  ai.op2(); 
}
```

then

```
int main()
{
   std::string type;
   std::cout << "which type do you need?"
   std::cin >> type;

   type == "int" ? do_stuff<int>() : do_stuff<float>();
}
```

Comment: it's going to be a very large function but I think it's the only possible way

Comment: @user3290180 Well, you can split it up into smaller functions. All you need is a single function template hook, how it is implemented is up to you.

Comment: how does that look like with a polymorphic lambda?